# How to search integer value using Hibernate with Lucene Search?

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

Unable to fetch results while searching on Integer field and data still exists. Could any one figure out what wrong i am doing?

```
 int status = 0;
 FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
 QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(ProcessActivity.class).get();
 System.out.println(""+status);
 org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = qb.keyword().onFields("status").matching(status).createQuery();

 FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, ProcessActivity.class);
 fullTextQuery.setFirstResult(0).setMaxResults(recordMaxLength);
 return fullTextQuery.getResultList();

//Following is main Entity text
@Fields({ @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO), @Field(name = "status", index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO) })
@Column(name = "STATUS")
public int getStatus() {
   return status;
}
```

Comment: Could you share the name of the target entity class, is it `ProcessActivity.class` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use NumericRangeQuery such as

```
NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("status", 1, value, value, true, true)
```

or by string phase such as

```
status[value TO value]
```